Firebase Reatime Database deploy error "TypeError: functions.database.ref is not a function"
The code seems fine, the modules needed seem up to date, the link to firebase is correct. However the function will not deploy and gives error...

TypeError: functions.database.ref is not a function

I removed gameinfo section as it's just setting variables and shouldn't impact at all
I apologise for probably not presenting this problem as is the norm. Please be kind and i will try again
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.database();

exports.matchmaker = functions.database.ref("/matchmaking/{playerId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const gameId = generateGameId();
      let secondPlayerKey = null;

      const snapshot = await db.ref("matchmaking").once("value");
      const players = snapshot.val();

      Object.keys(players).forEach((key) => {
        if (key !== context.params.playerId && !players[key].gameId) {
          secondPlayerKey = key;
        }
      });

      if (secondPlayerKey === null) {
        return null;
      }

      const matchmakingRef = db.ref("matchmaking");
      const transactionResult = await matchmakingRef.
          transaction((matchmaking) => {
            if (!matchmaking ||
              !matchmaking[context.params.playerId] ||
              !matchmaking[secondPlayerKey] ||
              matchmaking[context.params.playerId].gameId ||
              matchmaking[secondPlayerKey].gameId) {
              return matchmaking;
            }

            matchmaking[context.params.playerId].gameId = gameId;
            matchmaking[secondPlayerKey].gameId = gameId;
            return matchmaking;
          });

      if (!transactionResult ||
        transactionResult.snapshot.child(`${context.params.playerId}/gameId`).
            val() !== gameId) {
        return null;
      }

      const game = {
        gameInfo: {
          

      await db.ref(`games/${gameId}`).set(game);
      console.log("Game created successfully!");

      return null;
    });

I have tried checking compatibility of firebase functions and admin are okay.
I have re-installed the entire program and reset everything.
I have put these errors into chatG and followed the steps to the extent that i have exhausted its options provided (hence here).
Obviously, I simply want the function to deploy

If your firebase-functions dependency is fully up to date, then you're not using the correct API to build the function.  You're using the old v1 API, but you should be using the v2 API instead.  Use onValueCreated() instead of functions.database.ref.  See the examples in the documentation. For example:
const {onValueCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/database");

exports.makeuppercase = onValueCreated(
    "/messages/{pushId}/original",
    (event) => {

// your code goes here

});


ty. That sounds like another avenue to try.

It's not just "another" way.  It's the default, recommended way for new projects.  There is even a migration guide to get old projects up to date.  This is definitely the way to go unless you have some very specific reason not to.
